# Where is the IIS Express tray icon since Windows 11 and Visual Studio 2022?

Tags: blazor, visual-studio-2022, iis-express, windows-11

What is a prefered way to get to the configuration of IIS express ? The one launched by Visual Studio 2022 ?

I used to share access to the running Visual Studio iis developement app over the local network, tweaking iis express config.

In order to test and debug on other devices, like my phone.

Is there anyway to do that again?

I tried to find the IIS icon that used to be in the tray when Visual Studio was running a developpement web app.
I expected it to be there.

Answer (score 3):

You probably can forget about all those troubles in the past and use Visual Studio 2022 Dev Tunnels instead,

https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2022/11/18/dev-tunnels.aspx

Officially from Microsoft and fully supported.

[image]

Comment: In Visual Studio 2022 17.6+ the Preview Feature flag has been removed, it's enabled by default. Official docs are at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/dev-tunnels?view=aspnetcore-7.0.

Answer (score 0):

**Context:** When try to run a Web Application in a Windows computer.

**Solution:** Find the "IIS Express" option in the drop down next to your debug button. Reason: Kestrel is the default web server for ASP.NET Core projects, and it's cross-platform.